# Камень ножницы бумага

Tags: javascript

Дело в том что в коде, 2ю часть не распознает, всё что до "`var compare = function ( choice1, choice2 )`" распознает, а дальше вообще нет, так еще к этому всему не пишет кто выиграл, а пишет просто выбор компа, и к этому всему еще и в кавычках "paper" "scissors" "rock"

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var compare = function ( choice1, choice2 ){
    if ( choice1 === choice2 ){
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    if ( choice1 === "rock") {
        if ( choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins"
        }
    else {
        return "paper wins"
    }
}
if ( choice1 === "paper") {
   if ( choise2 === "rock") {
       return "paper wins"
   }
else {
    return "scissors wins"
}

}

if ( choise1 === "scissors") {
    if ( choise2 === "rock") {
        return "rock wins"
    }
    else {
        return "scissors wins"
    }
}

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Конструкция

```
var compare = function(choise1, choise2) {
   ...
};
```

создаёт функцию с именем `compare`, но не вызывает её. Такая конструкция аналогична этой:

```
function compare(choise1, choise2) {
    ...
}
```

Для получения результата нужно функцию вызвать и передать ей аргументы. Как-то так:

```
var result = compare(userChoise, computerChoise);
alert(result);
```

Также советую вам пересмотреть алгоритм сравнения. Вы сделали его слишком громоздким. Вот мой вариант:

```
function compare(choise1, choise2) {
    var gt = {
        'paper'    : 'rock',
        'rock'     : 'scissors',
        'scissors' : 'paper'
    };
    if (choise1 == choise2) {
        return 'draw';
    } else {
        return gt[choise1] == choise1 ? choise1 : choise2;
    }
}
```

Здесь объект `gt` показывает отношения между фигурами. Фигура до двоеточия (ключ), бьёт фигуру после двоеточия (значение). Для лучшего понимания моего варианта советую почитать про [объекты в JavaScript](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/intro). Если вам кажется, что мой вариант слишком сложен, попробуйте реализовать в рамках своего алгоритма сравнения игру "[камень, ножницы, бумага, ящерица, Спок](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C,_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B,_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0,_%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0,_%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA)" (тут, правда, понадобится небольшая модификация моего алгоритма, так как в этой игре одна фигура может бить две другие). Если и это вас не убедит, попробуйте реализовать [вот эту](http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/k/o/koskor/2328058_500.jpg) игру.

Comment: спасибо большое, если можно еще ваш скайп пожалуйста?

Comment: зачем у вас по два раза каждая сущность ? хватит и массива, сравниваем индексы, и считаем нулевой индекс больше максимального.

Comment: Согласен, тут имеет место некоторый оверинжениринг. Просто мне сразу пришёл в голову пример про "камень, ножницы, бумага, ящерица, Спок", там массивом не обойтись.

Comment: там как-то с четностью связано по моему... ну и можно всегда сделать массив

    [["камень",[2]],["ножницы"][0]],["бумага",[1]]]

где вторым описан массив тех индексов которые побеждают текущий

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, с математической точки зрения вы правы, игра циклична, решение хорошо выражается формулой и умещается в пару строк. Но с точки зрения программирования это крайне ненаглядно. В смысл моего кода вникнуть проще. А использование вами "магических чисел" (количество которых быстро возрастает с ростом количества фигур) также сильно затрудняет как понимание, так и поддержку вашего кода. Я уж молчу про фразу "в корне неверно". Неверным решение может быть лишь в случае если вы найдёте такие входные данные, на которых оно не будет.работать.

Comment: Посмотрите на код ТС'а и на мой. Код ТС'а индусятина ибо это жестосчайший неподдерживаемый хардкод. Ваш, кстати, тоже хардкодом попахивает, особенно для КНБЯС. Мой код - оверинжиниринг ибо не предполагает, что игра всегда будет цикличной, и задаёт её в виде графа. Насчёт синуса: не сравнивайте тёплое с мягким, а непрерывную функцию непрерывного аргумента с дискретной функцией дискретного аргумента, который, в свою очередь, принимает небольшое конечное число значений.

Comment: Зато мой вариант позволяет 1) задавать любые, в том числе нециклические, правила игры и 2) менять их в рантайме. Скажете, это скорее всего никому не нужно? Так в этом и есть суть оверинжиниринга - закладывание возможностей, которые _могут_ понадобится. А могут и нет. Дальнейшую дискуссию считаю бесполезной, посему предлагаю остаться при своих и разойтись.

Comment: @fori1ton я же сказал, для других правил(невыражаемых формулой) можно использовать ссылки на элементы массива (я использовал индексы, можно и просто ссылки, но инициализировать такой массив будет запарочно)

Comment: Наткнулся на ваш ответ) Вроде так вернее)  var gt = {
        'бумага'  : 'камень',
        'камень'  : 'ножницы',
        'ножницы' : 'бумага'
    };
    if (user_me == user_you) {
        alert( 'draw');
    } else {
        alert( gt[user_me] == user_you ? 1 : 0);
    } 1 - победа, 0 - поражение. Или не так?

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант. Все состояния прописываются только один раз. Количество состояний не ограничено. Основополагающими идеями взяты цикличность и честность (при нечётном числе вариантов).

```js
var states = ['paper', 'rock', 'scissors'];
states = states.concat(states);

function compare(res1, res2) {
  var i1 = states.indexOf(res1), i2 = states.indexOf(res2, i1);
  return i1==i2 ? 'draw' : i2-i1>states.length/4 ? 'loose' : 'win';
}

for (var q=0; q<states.length/2; ++q)
  for(var w=0; w<states.length/2; ++w)
    console.log("%s %s => %s", states[q], states[w], compare(states[q], states[w]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: @lafire, не лень было столько писать?

Comment: @fori1ton, мысль интересная, но при большом числе вариантов придётся перечислять квадратичное количество - по (n-1)/2 в каждой строке. Что-то не кажется мне этот вариант очень удобным в плане расширяемости.

Comment: @eicto, цикличность игры по сути является её основой. Без этого она бы не имела смысла. Зачем нужна расширяемость в этом направлении? Разумных мест для расширения кроме числа состояний я не вижу. А с этим та же проблема - квадратичный рост числа рёбер в графе.