# В игре камень, ножницы, бумага возвращает вместо ответа undefined

Tags: javascript

Функция "compare" почему то возвращает вместо ответа сравнения победителя, возвращает undefined. Помогите исправить код, чтобы функция работала правильно.

```
    var Human = {
        userChoice: function() {
            prompt('Ваш ход', 'камень, ножницы, бумага');
            return;
        }
    };
var userResult = Human.userChoice();

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "камень";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67 && computerChoice >= 0.35) {
    computerChoice = "бумага";
} else {
    computerChoice = "ножницы";
} 
alert("Компьютер: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1,choice2){
    if (choice1 == choice2){
        return "Ничья";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "камень") {
        if (choice2 === "ножницы") {
           return "Камень победил";
        }
        else {
            return "Бумага победила";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "бумага"){
        if (choice2 === "камень"){
            return "Бумага победила";
        }
        else {
            return "Ножницы победили";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "ножницы"){
        if (choice2 === "бумага"){
            return "Ножнецы победили";
        }
        else {
            return "Камень победил";
        }
    }
}
var result = compare(userResult,computerChoice);
alert(result);
```

Comment: Отлаживать код пробовали?

Comment: У вас в коде `userChoice()` возвращает void, а не строку.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/261037/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно зачем ты работаешь с функциями) 
Вот правильный код:

```js
var Human = prompt("Ваш ход. Введите камень, ножницы или бумага");


var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = 'камень';
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67 && computerChoice >= 0.35) {
  computerChoice = 'бумага';
} else {
  computerChoice = 'ножницы';
}
alert('Компьютер: ' + computerChoice);
console.log(computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 == choice2) {
    return 'Ничья';
  } else if (choice1 === 'камень') {
    if (choice2 === 'ножницы') {
      return 'Камень победил';
    } else {
      return 'Бумага победила';
    }
  } else if (choice1 === 'бумага') {
    if (choice2 === 'камень') {
      return 'Бумага победила';
    } else {
      return 'Ножницы победили';
    }
  } else if (choice1 === 'ножницы') {
    if (choice2 === 'бумага') {
      return 'Ножнецы победили';
    } else {
      return 'Камень победил';
    }
  }
}
var result = compare(Human, computerChoice);
alert(result);
```

Comment: computerChoice - не функция. Uncaught TypeError: computerChoice is not a function

Comment: Ок. Это я не увидел. А зачем у тебя выбор пользователя так сложно реализован? 
`var Human = {
        userChoice: function() {
            prompt('Ваш ход', 'камень, ножницы, бумага');
            return;
        }
    };`

Comment: Ну я могу просто реализовать var useChoice = prompt('Ваш ход', 'камень, ножницы, бумага'); и все будет работать, но хочу перенести весь код в обэкты. Начал переносить пользовательский выбор и функция compare начала выдавать undefined.

Comment: Так так и надо писать) Сейчас еще раз поправлю))

Comment: Спасибо тебе, уже решил, добавил переменную в метод обьэкта: var Human = {
  userChoice: function() {
   var userResult = prompt('Ваш ход', 'камень, ножницы, бумага'');
   return userResult;
  }
 };
 
 var userResult = Human.userChoice();