# Как можно определить победителя не прибегая к множеству if...else? Алгоритм приоритета выбора в игре камень-ножницы-бумага

Tags: python, python-3.x

Столкнулся с проблемой при написании игры "Камень,ножницы,бумага".Не знаю как грамотно выставить приоритет чтоб камень выигрывал у ножниц,ножницы у бумаги,а бумага у камня.При реализации следующим методом:

```py
array = ['камень','ножницы','бумага']
array[0] > array[1] > array[2] > array[0]
```

Камень выигрывал абсолютно у всех.Через кучу if..else реализовывать не буду!Подскажите,как правильно тут поступить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430668/178988

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На скорую руку, я бы попробовал так:

```
from itertools import cycle

array = ['бумага', 'ножницы','камень']
mycycle = cycle(array)

def testit(a, b):
    while next(mycycle) != a:
        pass
    if b == next(mycycle):
        print(f"{b} бьёт {a}")
    else:
        print(f"{a} бьёт {b}")
```

проверяем:

```
testit("ножницы", "камень")
```

> камень бьёт ножницы

```
testit("бумага", "камень")
```

> бумага бьёт камень