# Создать игру "камень-ножницы-бумага" js

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте! есть вот такой код, комп выбирает одно из слов рандом, user выбирает свой вариант цифрой 1, 2 или 3. Мне надо правильно сравнить. не могу понять как это сделать. при таком. что не так ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        let user1 = 0;
        let comp = 0;
        let computer = Math.random();
        if (computer <= 0.33){
            computer = 'камень';
        }else if (computer <= 0.64){
            computer = 'ножницы';
        }else {
            computer = 'бумага';
        }
        console.log(computer);
        while (true){
            const user = prompt('Введите один из вариантов\n1. камень \n2. ножницы\n3. бумага');
            const number = parseInt(user);
            if (user === null){
                console.log('Пользователь '+ user1 +'\nКомпьютер '+ comp)
                break;
            }
            if(computer === 'камень'){
                if (user === 3){
                    user1++;
                continue
                }
            }else {
                comp++;
            }
            if(computer === 'ножницы'){
                if (user === 1){
                    user1++;
                continue
                }
            }else {
                comp++;
            }
            if(computer === 'бумага'){
                if (user === 2){
                    user1++;
                }
            }else {
                comp++;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Сейчас у вас цикл вечный и значит выбор пользователем вариантов не прекратится. Ну а условие можно было бы писать как-то так: `if (computer === 'камень' && user === 3) ...`

Comment: это получается условие надо в не цикла писать ??

Comment: Это получается, нужно понять, как стоит задача. Просто сейчас вы из вашего цикла ни при каких условиях не выходите, а значит запрос к пользователю, чтобы он выбрал один из трёх пунктов не заканчивается.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430668/178988

Comment: Как-то писал эту [игру](http://pandora.clan.su/rps/), вот [JS](http://pandora.clan.su/rps/script.js) можете посмотреть как реализовано.

Comment: De.Minov у вас тут jquery используется, у меня по ТЗ на чистом js надо сделать)

Answer (score 5):

Виталий, желаю вам удачи в освоении программирования. Игры вполне для этого годятся. Что касается вашего кода в нем есть недочеты - поэтому он и не работал в частности проблема с условиями (лишний заход).

Предлагаю другое решение в плане кода, будет хорошо если вы в нем разберетесь, если что-то не будет понятно я отвечу в комментариях.

Итак у нас есть игра. У игры есть правила давайте их запишем. Это своеобразная `таблица подстановки`:

|  | камень | ножницы | бумага |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| камень | 0 | 1 | -1 |
| ножницы | -1 | 0 | 1 |
| бумага | 1 | -1 | 0 |

Такие таблицы используются в программировании, и документации,  они реально могут приносить пользу. Чтобы было удобно читать можно записать ее в коде в виде объекта. Очень важно чтобы код был читаем - Вы это позже оцените, всегда старайтесь писать так чтобы было меньше сложностей при чтении. Вложенные `if` достаточно сложны для восприятия.

Вот правила игры:

```
const gameRules = {
    "камень" : {
        "камень" :  0,
        "ножницы" : 1,  
        "бумага" : 0, //-1,
     }, 
    "ножницы" : {
        "камень" :  0,//-1,
        "ножницы" : 0,  
        "бумага" : 1,
    }, 
    "бумага" : {
        "камень" :  1,
        "ножницы" : 0, //-1,  
        "бумага" : 0,
    } 
}
```

это запись нашей таблицы истинности, для того чтобы вычислить результат мы пишем `gameRules['камень']['бумага']` т.е. если у нас `камень` а у соперника `бумага` то мы ничего не заработаем (или -1 бал - смотря как считать) тоже самое делаем со стороны компьютера.

В итоге остальной код выглядит так:

```
function getComputer() {
    const random = Math.random();
    if (random <= 0.33){
        computer = 'камень';
    } else if (random <= 0.64){
        computer = 'ножницы';
    } else {
        computer = 'бумага';
    }
    return computer;
}
    
while (true){
    const number = prompt('Введите один из вариантов\n1. камень \n2. ножницы\n3. бумага');
    if (!number) {
      break;
    }
    const user = ['камень', 'ножницы', 'бумага'][parseInt(number)-1];
    computer = getComputer();

    compScore += gameRules[computer][user] // считаем баллы компьютера
    userScore += gameRules[user][computer] // считаем баллы пользователя

    console.log(`Пользователь ${user} (${userScore})\nКомпьютер ${computer}(${compScore})`)                            
}
```

По объему строк практически то же самое, но такой код при определенной практике читается проще, легче контролируется и меняется. Конечно этот код не идеален и его тоже можно улучшить, в частности слова в коде обычно подменяют константами чтобы не наделать опечаток, и получение рандомного числа можно записать гораздо короче.

По поводу возможных улучшений вашего последнего варианта (разумеется нужно еще ввести проверку ввода пользователя, ну и это не предел улучшений):

```
const STONE = 0;
const SCISSORS = 1;
const PAPER = 2;

let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function getComputerChoise() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}

function getUserChoise (){
    const userChoise = prompt('Введите один из вариантов\n1. камень \n2. ножницы\n3. бумага');
    if (userChoise === null) {
        return userChoise;
    }
    return parseInt(userChoise) - 1; /* от 0 до 2*/
}

function gameStep() {
    const computerChoise = getComputerChoise();
    const userChoise = getUserChoise();
    if (!userChoise) return false;

    if (computerChoise === STONE && userChoise === PAPER 
        || computerChoise === SCISSORS && userChoise === STONE 
        || computerChoise === PAPER && userChoise === SCISSORS)
    {
        userScore++
    } else if (computerChoise === STONE && userChoise === SCISSORS 
        || computerChoise === SCISSORS && userChoise === PAPER
        || computerChoise === PAPER && userChoise === STONE){
        computerScore++
    }
    return true;
}

function showResults() {
    let result = 'Счет равен';
    if (userScore > computerScore){
        result ='Пользователь выиграл'
    }else if(userScore < computerScore){
        result = 'Компьютер выиграл';
    }
    console.log('Пользователь ' + userScore + '\nКомпьютер ' + computerScore + '\n' + result);
}

while (gameStep()) {}
showResults();
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniil Loban спасибо за ваш код, но мне надо было разобраться самому)
Вот к чему пришел. чувствую что здесь что то не то, как то он не правильно считает.
Подскажите пожалуйста что тут не так и как можно этот код сократить

```
let user1 = 0;
    let comp = 0;
    const getComputer = function () {
        let computer = Math.random();
        if (computer <= 0.33){
            computer = 'камень';
        }else if (computer <= 0.64){
            computer = 'ножницы';
        }else {
            computer = 'бумага';
        }
        return computer;
    }
    const random = function (computer, number) {
        if (computer === 'камень' && number === 3 || computer === 'ножницы' && number === 1 || computer === 'бумага' && number === 2){
            user1++
        }else if (computer === 'камень' && number === 2 || computer === 'ножницы' && number === 3 || computer === 'бумага' && number === 1){
            comp++
        }else {
        }
    }
    while (true) {
        const user = prompt('Введите один из вариантов\n1. камень \n2. ножницы\n3. бумага');
        const number = parseInt(user);
        if (user === null) {
            break
        }
        random(getComputer(),number);
    }
        console.log(user1);
        console.log(comp);

    if (user1 > comp){
        result ='Пользователь выиграл'
    }else if(user1 === comp){
        result = 'Счет равен'
    }else {
        result = 'Компьютер выиграл'
    }
    console.log('Пользователь ' + user1 + '\nКомпьютер ' + comp + '\n' + result)
```

Comment: Виталий, это лучше первого варианта. Хорошо что пытаетесь разбираться сами - это важно. Думаю счет правильный, будет хорошо повысить читабельность кода, согласитесь (`computer` === 'камень' && `number === 3` ) читается хуже чем (`computer` === 'камень' && `user === 'бумага'` ). Cократить можно функцию getComputer. Это конечно выглядит как придирки, но это важно. Думаю будет не лишним почитать книгу  "Чистый код", она поможет вовремя выработать полезные привычки. Желаю успеха! Не останавливайтесь!

Comment: я дополнил свой ответ, возможными улучшениями этого кода

Answer (score 1):

> как можно этот код сократить

```
const p1 = Number(prompt('1. Камень \n2. Ножницы\n3. Бумага')) - 1,
      p2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
      p1win = [1,2,0][p1] === p2,
      Enum = ['Камень', 'Ножницы', 'Бумага'],
      result = p1 === p2 ? 'Ничья' : 'Выиграл ' + (p1win ? 'Игрок 1' : 'Игрок 2');

console.log("Результат: " + result, '|', "Игрок: " + Enum[p1], '|', "Компьютер: " + Enum[p2]);
```

+ Бонус

```
const p1 = Number(prompt('1. Камень \n2. Ножницы\n3. Бумага\n4. Ящерица\n5. Спок')) - 1,
      p2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
      p1win = [[1,3],[2,3],[0,4],[4,2],[0,1]][p1].includes(p2),
      Enum = ['Камень', 'Ножницы', 'Бумага', 'Ящерица', 'Спок'],
      result = p1 === p2 ? 'Ничья' : 'Выиграл ' + (p1win ? 'Игрок 1' : 'Игрок 2');

console.log("Результат: " + result, '|', "Игрок: " + Enum[p1], '|', "Компьютер: " + Enum[p2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
       const select = prompt("Что хотите? Бумага , Ножницы, Камень")
        const items = ['Бумага', 'Ножницы', 'Камень']

        if (!select) {
            location.reload()
        } else {
            document.write(`<p>Вы: ${select}</p>`)
        }

        let selectComputer = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

        document.write(`<p>Робот: ${selectComputer}</p>`);

        const compare = (choice1,choice2) => {
            if (choice1 === choice2) {
                return "Ничья";
            }
            if (choice1 === "камень") {
                if (choice2 === "ножницы") {
                    return "Вы выиграли!";
                } else {
                    return "Вы проиграли!";
                }
            }
            if (choice1 === "бумага") {
                if (choice2 === "камень") {
                    return "Вы выиграли!";
                } else {
                    return "Вы проиграли!";
                }
            }
            if (choice1 === "ножницы") {
                if (choice2 === "камень") {
                    return "Вы проиграли!";
                } else {
                    return "Вы выиграли";
                }
            }

            return 'Начните игру заново!'
        };

        const result = compare(select.toLowerCase(),selectComputer.toLowerCase());

        document.write(`<br><hr><br> ${result}`);
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}::selection{background:#fb9fe5;text-shadow:none}a{color:#0088CC;text-decoration:none;outline:0}a:hover{color:#005580}a img{border:none}img{max-width:100%}html{font-size:100%}body{padding:5%;font:300 1.25em/1.6 monospace;background:#eee;color:#000;}h1{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;line-height:1;font-weight:300;margin-bottom:1em;}
```